# Reference for scattered spaces

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

Is there a good reference for the following well-known facts:

> Given a topological space $X$, the following are equivalent:
>
> 1. $X$ is scattered, i.e. every nonempty subspace of $X$ has an isolated point.
> 2. For some ordinal $\alpha$ the $\alpha$-th Cantor-Bendixson derivative $X^{(\alpha)}$ of $X$ is empty.

And also,

> Every second-countable scattered space is countable.

? If the same reference also contains additional equivalences is more than welcome.
Thanks

Comment: [This paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/016686419400093I) is a good reference for scattered and related spaces. Probably in one of the papers cited there, you will also find references to your questions.

Comment: BTW: in your second question, "second-countable" can be weakened to "hereditarily Lindelöf".

Comment: @Ulli thanks, but the linked paper doesn't seem to give an explicit definition of scattered space, let alone the characterization in terms of the Cantor-Bendixson derivative..

Comment: Several versions of this decomposition are given in [this 21 January 2003 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/046wt0BrqfY/m/K-5wJNBbhA8J). These results can be found (sometimes in the problems/exercises) in many of the standard general topology texts (other than especially elementary texts like Kasriel, Mendelson, Gamelin/Green, etc.), such as those by Kelly, Dugundji, Wilansky, Gaal, Cullen, Munkres, Engelking, Willard, Thron, Schubert, Pervin, etc. For *scattered spaces* in particular, see [these publications](https://zbmath.org/?q=ti%3A%22scattered+spaces%22).

Comment: See also Section 8.5: *Scattered spaces* (pp. 147-151) in Zbigniew Semadeni, [**Banach Spaces of Continuous Functions**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0006C5WEQ), Monografie Matematyczne #55, PWN--Polish Scientific Publishers, 1971, 584 pages.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thanks a lot,  Semadeni's monograph is precisely what I was looking for.